# What are the points considered when a database table is created?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I know it is a big and general question. Let me describe what I am looking for.

In big projects, we have some entities with many properties. (Many is over 100 properties for just a specific entity.) These properties have one to one relation. By the time goes, these tables with many columns are really big problems for maintenance and further development.

As you think, these 90 columns is created in a time with many projects. Not a single project. Therefore, requirements affect the table design in a wide time duration.

i.e. : There is a table to store information of payments between banks in global.

- Some columns are foreign keys of others.(Customer, TransferType etc.)
- Some columns are parameters of current payment. (IsActive, IsLoaded, IsOurCustomer etc.)
- Some columns are fields of payment. (Information Bank, Receiver Bank etc.)
  and so on.

These fields are always counting and now we have about 90 columns with one to one relation.

What are the concerns to divide a table to smaller tables. I know normalization rules and I am not interested it. (Already duplicated columns are normalized)

I try to find some patterns or some rules to divide a table which has one to one relation among columns.

Comment: If many columns are NULLable, especially if many of them are only applicable to certain types of rows, you probably have some kind of class/sub-class entity, in which case it may make sense to move the columns to one or more child tables with a 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the columns are only dependent on the primary table key and are not repeating (phone1, phone2) they should be part of the same table. If you split a table  you will have to do joins when you need all the columns of the table. If many of the values are null you may investigate the use of sparse columns (which don't take up any room if they have a null value).